# URL percent encoding query param Bing API Java

Tags: java, http, encoding, uri, bing-api

I'm trying to URL percent encode my query param value while using URIBuilder to make an HTTP request to Bing API.

The url looks like

```
"https://api.datamarket.azure.com/Data.ashx/Bing/SearchWeb/v1/Web?$format=json&Query="
```

Where the Query String must be like 
    %27Test%20query%27

Using URLEncoder.encode(string, code), a string such as "test query", gets turned into "test+query" which is unacceptable.

```
URIUtil.encodeQuery()
```

returns "test%20query" which is almost acceptable, except it needs the %27 at the beginning and end.

When I try to just concatenate the string to make it valid as such, and then load this into URIBuilder, URIBuilder ends up with

```
https://api.datamarket.azure.com/Data.ashx/Bing/SearchWeb/v1/Web?%24format=json&Query=%2527test%2520query%2527
```

which is again unacceptable.

How can I remedy this issue? It's driving me insane.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is encoded URI. 
$   is %24
bank is %20

if you want real URI, you need to decode .

I think decode method works well for you.

reference here:

http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/apidocs/org/apache/commons/httpclient/util/URIUtil.html

Comment: Thank you very much, does URI encode the URL by default as well?

Comment: maybe default is encode, but you can setting on your WAS. if you use tomcat or any web application server. you can find the option.